# Gradle: cycles in dependency insight report

Tags: java, gradle, jackson, jooq, circular-dependency

Trying to upgrade some javax to jakarta libraries, I ran into version conflicts. In particular, one of my libraries (jOOQ) that I **need** to update requires version `3.0.0` of `jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api` (which is in the jarkarta namespace), but the jackson xml libraries still require the old `2.3.3` (which is in the javax namespace).

Apart from not knowing how to resolve the situation, I got further confused by the following dependencyInsight report (generated with `:<myproject>:dependencyInsight --configuration compileClasspath --dependency jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api`):

```
jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.0
\--- org.jooq.pro-java-11:jooq:3.16.5
     \--- compileClasspath

jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3 -> 3.0.0
\--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.13.4
     +--- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.36 (requested com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.13.3)
     |    +--- compileClasspath (requested org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson)
     |    \--- org.glassfish.jersey:jersey-bom:2.36
     |         \--- compileClasspath
     \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.13.4
          +--- compileClasspath
          +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.13.4
          |    +--- compileClasspath
          |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.13.4 (*)
          +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.13.4 (*)
          +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.4
          |    +--- compileClasspath (requested com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind)
          |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.13.4 (*)
          |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.36 (requested com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.3) (*)
          |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.13.4 (*)
          |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.13.4 (*)
          +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.4
          |    +--- compileClasspath (requested com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations)
          |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.13.4 (*)
          |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.36 (requested com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.3) (*)
          |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.13.4 (*)
          |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.4 (*)
          |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.13.4 (*)
          \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.4
               +--- compileClasspath (requested com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core)
               +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.13.4 (*)
               +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.13.4 (*)
               +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.4 (*)
               \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.13.4 (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

As you can see, there are unexpected entries in the report:

- `com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.13.4` seems to depend on itself (i.e. cycles).
- Other libraries like `om.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.13.4` seem to depend on `com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.13.4` although I can't find that dependency when inspecting the POM file.

Can someone explain why the dependency insight report is generated that way? And, ultimately, do you have any hints at how I can get the jackson xml stuff to work with jakarta xml bindings?

Comment: jackson-bom is a special dependency called a Bill of Materials (BOM) - it is used to ensure all your jackson dependencies have matching versions (2.13.4 in this case) - see https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.13.4/jackson-bom-2.13.4.pom and its packagaing is 'pom' as opposed to 'jar'

Comment: @PJFanning so you mean that because of the special role of a BOM, Gradle shows a dependency from any lib of a BOM to the BOM itself?

Comment: Why do you "*need*" to update jOOQ?

Comment: Because jOOQ is our main "ORM" and we want the latest features. The transition from javax to jakarta is something that needs to be done eventually anyway.